# http access to almost (by jumping) remote server

Tags: networking, ssh

have a client computer 192.168.1.137 and a Kodi server on rpi 2 ip:192.168.1.51 and the point of interest is my tp-link RE305 extender running OpenWRT latest version. IP:192.168.1.13

I can't access the tp-link re305, but if i access the Kodi and then from that i can access the tp-link RE 305. And i can also do it by this jump command: ssh -J root@192.168.1.51 root@192.168.1.13. What i need is http access from my client to my tp-link. I have no idea on how to do that if at all possible. Best regards.

Comment: If it is only an extender, you should be able to reach it unless you have restricted access to certain IPs or MAC addresses, which is most probably the case. Access your extender through the Kodi server and configure access controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use TCP port forwarding (which `-J` option uses under the hood too):

```
ssh root@192.168.1.51 -L 8080:192.168.1.13:80
```

Now, point your browser to `localhost:8080`, and SSH will tunnel that to `192.168.1.13:80`, which will see the connection as originating from `192.168.1.13`.

Another way is to use socks proxy built into OpenSSH client (there is no need to do anything on the server side to support this, because it again uses the same TCP tunelling internally, so `dropbear` server in the OpenWRT will work):

```
ssh root@192.168.1.51 -D 6543
```

Now, set up a SOCKS proxy in your browser on the localhost:6543. Any HTTP request which will be routed through this SOCKS proxy, will be sent to SSH peer and the further HTTP connection will appear originating from `192.168.1.51`.

---

Both should be started by hand. There is no way of starting any of them on demand when you try to access something from the browser. But, depending on your system, you may create a service which starts, say, a ssh SOCKS proxy during system boot.

Comment: Just to make sure for anybody this command is working.
ssh root@192.168.1.51 -L 8080:192.168.1.13:80
Thanks for your spot on recommendation.
Best regards
Rikard

Comment: Then please accept answer to stop this question from floating indefinitely as "not answered" and to make sure anybody will see this problem is solved (and to give me +15 rep).